# Count the overlapping values between two tables?

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, duplicates

I have two tables that are structured the same with a sequence column and I am trying to count  the number of sequences that show up in two different tables. 
I am using this right now:

```
SELECT A.sequence FROM p2.pool A WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * from
p1.pool B WHERE B.sequence = A.sequence)
```

And then I was going to count the number of results. 
Is there an easier way to do this using COUNT so I don't have to get all of the results first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an easier way using `COUNT`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM p2.pool A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM p1.pool B
              WHERE B.sequence = A.sequence)
```

You could also use a join instead of a subquery, but the speed is unlikely to change:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM p2.pool A
JOIN p1.pool B ON A.sequence = B.sequence
```